# How to get the index of a selected item in autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the autocomplete feature of jQueryUI. It correctly gives list the items and I'm able to make a selection from the list. The problem I'm having is how to get the index of the selected item which is from an array used in the source event.

```
var options = {
    select: function() {
        // problem is here, I'm not able to see the correct index number of the selected item and always say -1
        alert($.inArray($("#searchAText").val()), arrayA); 
    },
    source: function(req, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(reg, term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re + "i");
        response($.grep(arrayA, function(item, index) {
            return matcher.test(item);
        })); 
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
     alert($.inArray(ui.item.value, arrayA));
}
```

Comment: @Yetimwork Beyene See my editing, I'm sure that's what you were looking for.

Comment: what does availableTags do?

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene +1 for your question cause a few days ago I was looking a lot for a question like this :)